# Odd Parameter I dont understand in gridlabd threadpool.c

Tags: c++

I'm working on the open project gridlabd hosted at sourceforge. I was trying to call the `create_thread` function: `static __inline int create_thread(void * (*proc)(void *), void *arg)`

I just don't understand for the life of me what in the world `void * (*proc)(void *)` means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`void * (*proc)(void *)` is a pointer to a function which returns `void*` and accepts `void*` as an argument.

Comment: I thought it was some kind of crazy typecasting that was going on that I didn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pointer to a function, said function taking a void pointer as an argument and returning a void pointer.

In other words, you can do:

```
void *threadMain (void *arg) { while (1) doSomething(); }

int stat = create_thread (threadMain, NULL);
```

to create a thread using the function `threadMain` as it's procedure.